# Simple Stored Procedure Question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am creating a simple stored procedure in VS 2010/SQL Server 2008 as follows:

`CREATE PROCEDURE ReturnPrice
 @carID int
 @price decimal(18,2) output
AS
SELECT @price = Price FROM Cars WHERE CarID =  @carID`

and I am receiving the following error message when attempting to save:

Incorrect syntax near '@price'
Must declare the scalar variable "@price"

Any pointers or tips as to where I am going wrong will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to separate your parameters with commas!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReturnPrice 
   @carID int,
   @price decimal(18,2) output 
AS 
   SELECT 
      @price = Price 
   FROM 
      dbo.Cars 
   WHERE 
      CarID = @carID
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind i realised it was a simple syntax error, missing a comma!!!

Comment: In the future please write that as a comment to the answer you`re refering to and accept the answer