# Understanding simple stored procedure: Moving output to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm hoping I can get some help with understanding a simple stored procedure.
Basically, I want to store the output of a select statement in a variable and then print out the value of the variable.

I found a very similar question here: 
[Simple Stored Procedure Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820255/simple-stored-procedure-question)

And the code looks as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReturnPrice 
   @carID int,
   @price decimal(18,2) output 
AS 
   SELECT 
      @price = Price 
   FROM 
      dbo.Cars 
   WHERE 
      CarID = @carID
```

My question is this: How do I get the value of @carID?

If I try this:

```
declare @carOutput varchar(50)
exec carInformation, '@carOutput varchar(50) output',  @carOutput output
```

I get an error of:

```
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Line 3: Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Thank you!

Comment: "How do I get the value of @carID?" -- how did you want to 'get it'? Within the proc, as another output variable, etc? It's not clear on how you want to *use* the @carID. What is `carInformation` vs. `ReturnPrice`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
exec carInformation, '@carOutput varchar(50) output',  @carOutput output
                   ^bad

exec carInformation  '@carOutput varchar(50) output',  @carOutput output
                   ^good
```

but also `'@carOutput varchar(50) output'` must be an int, but you are passing in a string

you need to have the calling application already know the value for @carID, and the procedure uses that value to return the price.

so try something like:

```
DECLARE @CarID_x int
       ,@Price_x decimal(18,2)

SET @CarID_x=123

EXEC ReturnPrice @CarID, @Price_x OUTPUT 
PRINT @Price_x
```

or

```
DECLARE @Price_x decimal(18,2)

EXEC ReturnPrice 123, @Price_x OUTPUT 
PRINT @Price_x
```

both code examples above will return the `Price` column value for the `dbo.Cars` row that has the `CarID` value of `123`.

If you don't know the `CarID` then run:

```
SELECT 
      CarID, Price 
   FROM dbo.Cars
```

and you will get a result set containing all the prices for all the cars.